# Why the data are not passed through HTTP Post request to the backend in Angular

Tags: javascript, python, angular, flask, post

I am using Angular + Flask to build up a webapp. Now I am having difficulties to pass the data from the front end to the backend. The related code is as following:
app.service.ts

```
upload(data: JSON):Observalbe<any> {
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
url = 'xxxxx\upload'
return this.http.post<JSON>(url, data, {headers: headers}).pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

On the backend side, I have:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_data():
    print(request.method)              # POST
    data = request.form
    print(data)                        # ImmutableMultiDict([]) and empty
    ...
```

So the server receives empty data. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the angular code and check the data inside the upload function? Btw, is this the exact code you are running as it will cause compilation errors (Observalbe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the backend python, do:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_data():
    data=request.data
```

Then data will be seen.